# MissingPropertyException even though it's imported

Tags: groovy

I'm working on some integration tests in Groovy. There are a few hundred tests and I've been tasked with removing hardcoded ID's in favor of a single file with constants. For about 500 of the files, everything works as expected (Thanks, grep and sed): hardcoded ID's have been replaced with a constant:

**old**

```
package com.example.package.tests;

class SomeTest extends BaseGroovyTest { 

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {           
        def merchantId = "1234"

        ...
    }
}
```

**new**

```
package com.example.package.tests;
import com.example.package.util.ConstantMerchants

class SomeTest extends BaseGroovyTest { 

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {           
        def merchantId = ConstantMerchants.MERCHANT_A

        ...
    }
}
```

**ConstantMerchants**

```
package com.example.package.util;

public final class ConstantMerchants {

    public static final String MERCHANT_A = "1234";
    public static final String MERCHANT_B = "1111";
    public static final String MERCHANT_C = "2222";
    public static final String MERCHANT_D = "3333";
    ...

    private ConstantMerchants() { }

}
```

However, while some files were changed successfully (so the hardcoded ID is replaced with a reference to `ConstantMerchants` and `ConstantMerchants` is imported), their tests can't run due to the error:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ConstantMerchants for class: com.example.package.tests.SomeTest

I've checked multiple times, and the only modifications to the files are the addition of an import station for `ConstantMerchants`, and the replacement of a string ID with a `ConstantMerchants` counterpart.

Removing the import statement and then having eclipse add it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (Organize imports) results in the same file I had before removing the import statement, and the error still occurring.

Any help in resolving this issue would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Is it consistently reproducible? what is the gdk and jdk versions?

Comment: This issue occurs for the same tests every time, regardless of if I run any other tests together with them. I'm using Java SE 1.7 (I'm not sure how to give you a more specific version from Eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently some class that was used by a class that was used by a class (...) that was used by my test referenced `ConstantMerchants` but didn't properly import it.

For some reason the compiler thought this was the fault of the class at the end of the usage chain so it kept saying my tests were missing references while it was actually some util class a few layers deep. Adding the import to that file fixed the issue.

I finally found this by grepping for files that contain `ConstantMerchants` but not the import statement. If anyone is interested, my grep command was:

```
grep -L -e "import .*ConstantMerchants" $(grep -E -f /mnt/c/Data/search_replaced.txt * -rclH)
```

Where `search_replaced.txt` contains a few patterns that match the replaced IDs.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you have many tests running and some of them fails. That makes me think that there is a **dependency problem** of your tests, means maybe some tests are not allowed to have the class **ConstantMerchants** in their import correctly.
Do the following:

- Try to change the class **ConstantMerchants** position where all the tests have an access to that class.

Another thing you should check is your IDE synchronization:

- Delete the **build** directory.
- Rebuild the project.

Check if that helped.

No, then check for any other synchronization issues of the IDE.

If it didn't work, try another thing: 
Check your building tool if it has some limitations or any Environment variable it needs for running in the best way.

And do the follows:

- Delete the build directory
- Perform a synchronization to the project libraries.
- Rerun the project. 
  Most of the time it works great and can help eliminate that error.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked, the `ConstantMerchants` class is located in a package above the tests, I guess that means all tests have access to it. Rebuilding or re-importing the project doesn't seem to help anything.

Comment: Did you checked any dependencies issues? The solutions I added in the answer may help the project dependencies in any case of missing class etc..

Comment: I found the issue. Apparently some class that was used by a class that was used by a class (...) that was used by my test referenced `ConstantMerchants` but didn't properly import it. For some reason the compiler thought this was the fault of the class at the end of the usage chain so it kept saying my tests were missing references while it was actually some util class a few layers deep. Adding the import to that file fixed the issue.

Comment: As I thought this was a synchronization problem between the class you wish to have and the class the the code refers too. I am glad you have found the problem. Good luck :-)